# in React Application, my loader take Infinite load time on mobile device but in pc work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, infinite-loop, loader

**in React Application, my loader take Infinite load time on mobile device but in pc work properly.**

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const handleLoading = () => setLoading(false);
  const submitUnloadedTrace = () => {
const payload = {
  siteVisitData: {
    siteVisitAt,
    siteLeaveAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    pageVisitData: [...pageVisitData,
      {
        pageName,
        pageVisitAt,
        pageLeaveAt: new Date().toISOString(),
      }]
  },
};

if (activityTrace?._id) {
  const { siteVisitData, } = payload;
  api.requestUpdateActivityTrace({ siteVisitData, id: activityTrace._id });
}
 };

 useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('load', handleLoading);
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', submitUnloadedTrace);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('load', handleLoading);
      submitUnloadedTrace();
   };
 }, []);

{ loading && <BrandAnimation /> }
```

why is it not work in mobile devices and what the solution?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it in an emulated mobile device with the browser dev tools? Are you sure that the mobile device you're resting on is actually loading data from your API correctly? The code you have should run on any device: so it seems like the issue comes from the specific mobile device itself rather than the code.

Comment: Hi Arnab,

Is this issue happening after building?

Comment: @SourabhKumar yes and run time also in localhost.

Comment: Can you please share some more code snippets or upload them on stackblitz?